# Recyclerview not working properly

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have created a program following all the steps that I found online. What it does is if I have a connection it sends a data to remote server and server responses OK if data entry is successful. My app works fine on saving data to the server side but it does not display on my recyclerview. But when I switch to airplane mode and try to send data to server, It displays on recyclerview that it failed but when it succeeds, it does not show up on recyclerview. Maybe you guys can help. I can't seem to find the error.

**Main activity**

```
public class SMSActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

RecyclerView smsRecyclerview;
EditText Smsplace;
RecyclerView.LayoutManager smsLayoutmanager;
SMSAdapter smsAdapter;
ArrayList<SMS> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sms);

    smsRecyclerview = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.smsRecyclerView);
    Smsplace = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.smsplace);
    smsLayoutmanager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    smsRecyclerview.setLayoutManager(smsLayoutmanager);
    smsRecyclerview.setHasFixedSize(true);
    smsAdapter = new SMSAdapter(arrayList);
    smsRecyclerview.setAdapter(smsAdapter);
    readFromLocalStorage();

}

public void submitPlace(View view)
{
    String smsplace = Smsplace.getText().toString();
    saveToAppServer(smsplace);
    Smsplace.setText("");
}

private void readFromLocalStorage()
{
    arrayList.clear();
    SMSHelper smsHelper = new SMSHelper(this);
    SQLiteDatabase database = smsHelper.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = smsHelper.readFromLocalDatabase(database);

    while (cursor.moveToNext())
    {
        String smsplace = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(SMSContract.SMSPLACE));
        int smssync_status = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(SMSContract.SMSSYNC_STATUS));
        arrayList.add(new SMS(smsplace,smssync_status));
    }

    smsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    cursor.close();

}

private void saveToAppServer(final String smsplace)
{


    if(checkNetworkConnection())
    {
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, SMSContract.SERVER_URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {

                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                            String Response = jsonObject.getString("response");
                            if(Response.equals("OK"))
                            {
                                saveToLocalStorage(smsplace,SMSContract.SMSSYNC_STATUS_OK);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                saveToLocalStorage(smsplace,SMSContract.SMSSYNC_STATUS_FAILED);
                            }

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                saveToLocalStorage(smsplace,SMSContract.SMSSYNC_STATUS_FAILED);

            }
        })
        {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("smsplace",smsplace);
                return params;
            }
        }
        ;
        SMSSingleton.getInstance(SMSActivity.this).addToRequestQue(stringRequest);
    }
    else
    {
        saveToLocalStorage(smsplace,SMSContract.SMSSYNC_STATUS_FAILED);
    }


}

public boolean checkNetworkConnection()
{
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected());
}

private void saveToLocalStorage(String smsplace,int smssync)
{
    SMSHelper smsHelper = new SMSHelper(this);
    SQLiteDatabase database = smsHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    smsHelper.saveToLocalDatabase(smsplace,smssync,database);
    readFromLocalStorage();
}

}
```

**RecyclerAdapter**

```
public class SMSAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SMSAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

private ArrayList<SMS> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();


public SMSAdapter(ArrayList<SMS> arrayList)
{
    this.arrayList = arrayList;
}


@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.smsitem_view,parent,false);
    return new MyViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.Smsplace.setText(arrayList.get(position).getSmsplace());
    int smssync_status = arrayList.get(position).getSmsSync_status();
    if(smssync_status == SMSContract.SMSSYNC_STATUS_OK)
    {
        holder.Smssync_status.setImageResource(R.drawable.ok);
    }
    else
    {
        holder.Smssync_status.setImageResource(R.drawable.sync);
    }

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return arrayList.size();
}

public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{

    ImageView Smssync_status;
    TextView Smsplace;

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        Smssync_status = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.smsImgsync);
        Smsplace = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtSmsplace);
    }
}

}
```

***P.S. I didn't include the sqlitedatabase codes. But if you guys need it. I'd be happy to.

Comment: Please debug your code to check is the data from database successfully sent (or fetched) and then mention it?

Comment: please post your XML as well. A lot of times the problem is in the XML. Post for the activity as well as the recyclerview item.